# SDL/OpenGL Double Buffering Memory Leak

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks, sdl

So I've been trying to make my own mini-engine for a game using SDL and OpenGL, with the main game logic contained inside of a singleton class. But for the life of me I can't figure out how I'm getting a memory leak with this sample portion of the engine, although I'm pretty certain that it occurs whenever I call SDL_GL_SwapBuffers. The leak is about 4 K every few two or three seconds. I'm using SDL 1.3; please help me find the leak, it's been driving me crazy for the past week!

### MainModule.h

```
#ifndef MAINMODULE_H
#define MAINMODULE_H

/// Includes
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_opengl.h"
#include <string>

/// Define Statements (Screen elements)
#define MAINMODULE_WIDTH 800
#define MAINMODULE_HEIGHT 600
#define MAINMODULE_CAPTION "MainModule"

/// Define Statements (OpenGL memory usage)
#define MAINMODULE_RED_SIZE 8
#define MAINMODULE_GREEN_SIZE 8
#define MAINMODULE_BLUE_SIZE 8
#define MAINMODULE_ALPHA_SIZE 8
#define MAINMODULE_BUFFER_SIZE 32
#define MAINMODULE_DEPTH_SIZE 16
#define MAINMODULE_DOUBLEBUFFER 1 // 1 to Enable
#define MAINMODULE_FLAGS SDL_OPENGL

/// Define Statements (OpenGL elements)
#define MAINMODULE_CLEARCOLOR 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
#define MAINMODULE_SHADEMODEL GL_SMOOTH
#define MAINMODULE_DEPTH_TEST 0 // 1 to Enable

class MainModule {

    private: // Constructor/Deconsctuctor

        MainModule();
        ~MainModule();

    private: // Class Variables

        static MainModule* _Instance;       // Singleton instance of the module.

        static int _Width;                  // Width of the game screen.
        static int _Height;                 // Height of the game screen.
        static std::string _Caption;        // Game screen caption/title.
        static SDL_Surface* _ScreenSurface; // Game screen as represented by the window.
        static SDL_Event* _Event;   // Events such as mouse/key input.

        static bool _IsInitialized;         // Has the engine been initialized?
        static bool _IsRunning;             // Is the engine running?

    public: // Get/Set Functions

        static inline int Width() { return _Width; }
        static inline int Height() { return _Height; }
        static inline std::string Caption() { return _Caption; }

        static inline bool IsInitialized() { return _IsInitialized; }
        static inline bool IsRunning() { return _IsRunning; }

        static void SetCaption(std::string caption);

    public: // Class Functions

        static void ConstructInstance();
        static void DeconstructInstance();

        static void InitializeModule();
        static void RunGameLogic();                         // Updates and renders game information.

};

#endif // MAINMODULE_H
```

### MainModule.ccp

```
/// Includes
#include "MainModule.h"
#include <iostream>

// Static Variable Declarations
MainModule* MainModule::_Instance = 0;
int MainModule::_Width = MAINMODULE_WIDTH;
int MainModule::_Height = MAINMODULE_HEIGHT;
std::string MainModule::_Caption = MAINMODULE_CAPTION;
SDL_Surface* MainModule::_ScreenSurface = 0;
SDL_Event* MainModule::_Event = 0;
bool MainModule::_IsInitialized = false;
bool MainModule::_IsRunning = false;

/// Constructor/Deconstructor
MainModule::MainModule() { }

MainModule::~MainModule() { 
    if (_Event != 0) delete _Event;
    if (_ScreenSurface != 0) SDL_FreeSurface(_ScreenSurface);
    SDL_Quit();
}

/// Set Functions
void MainModule::SetCaption(std::string caption)
{ _Caption = caption; if (_IsInitialized) SDL_WM_SetCaption(_Caption.c_str(), 0); }

/// Class Functions
void MainModule::ConstructInstance()
{ if (_Instance == 0) _Instance = new MainModule(); }

void MainModule::DeconstructInstance()
{ if (_Instance != 0) { delete _Instance; _Instance = 0; } }

void MainModule::InitializeModule() {
    ConstructInstance(); // Create an instance if the ConstructInstance function wasn't created before.
    if (_Instance == 0) { printf("MainModule instance not created properly./n"); return; } 

    // Initialize SDL.
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) { printf("SDL Initialization error: %s/n", SDL_GetError()); return; }

    // Set OpenGL memory usage.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, MAINMODULE_RED_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, MAINMODULE_GREEN_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, MAINMODULE_BLUE_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, MAINMODULE_ALPHA_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, MAINMODULE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, MAINMODULE_DEPTH_SIZE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, MAINMODULE_DOUBLEBUFFER);

    // Creates the screen and window.
    _ScreenSurface = SDL_SetVideoMode(MAINMODULE_WIDTH, MAINMODULE_HEIGHT, MAINMODULE_BUFFER_SIZE, MAINMODULE_FLAGS);
    if (_ScreenSurface == 0) { printf("ScreenSurface not created properly./n"); return; }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption(_Caption.c_str(), 0);

    (MAINMODULE_DEPTH_TEST == 1) ? glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) : glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(MAINMODULE_CLEARCOLOR);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    _IsInitialized = true;
    _IsRunning = true;
    _Event = new SDL_Event();
}

void MainModule::RunGameLogic() {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(_Event)) { // Event handling loop
        switch (_Event->type) {
            case SDL_QUIT: // Exits out of game
            { _IsRunning = false; break; }
            case SDL_ACTIVEEVENT:
            { break; }
            case SDL_KEYDOWN: // Keyboard press down
            { break; }
            case SDL_KEYUP: // Keyboard press up
            { break; }
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: // Mouse movement
            { break; }
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: // Mouse button down
            { break; }
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP: // Mouse button up
            { break; }
        }
    }

    // Rendering logic
    (MAINMODULE_DEPTH_TEST == 1) ? glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) : glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}

/// Entry point for the program
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MainModule::InitializeModule();
    if (MainModule::IsInitialized()) { // If the modules initialized sucessfully
        while (MainModule::IsRunning()) { MainModule::RunGameLogic(); }
    }
    MainModule::DeconstructInstance();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OS?  Which revision of SDL 1.3?  OpenGL implementation vendor?  How are you determining that a leak has occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Generally that sort of issue relates to internal issues with the underlying OpenGL libraries, the compiler, or something of that sort - graphics code like that is [notorious](http://www.dsource.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3880&sid=eec13c3dda20b73027ab86d873b4ad43) for being a bit buggy and finicky.

If you give a few more details I may be able to give some more help - what operating system, compiler, graphics driver/version, specific SDL version down to build, etc.

In the mean time, consider compiling under another operating system and see what happens, or switch out SDL version.

But yeah, almost certain you're not doing anything wrong...